# GLSL looped assignment -> "invalid operation"

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to get a polynomial equation solver to work in GLSL, but it fails when I include this small section of code:

```
//bs_a: start of monotonic section
//bs_b: end
//factor: 1.0 if bs_a < bs_b and -1.0 else
for (int iter = 0; iter < bisectionIterations; iter++) {
    bs_m = mix(bs_a, bs_b, 0.5);
    if (poly_calculatevalue(in_p, bs_m) * factor < 0.0)
        bs_a = mix(bs_a, bs_b, 0.5);
    else bs_b = bs_m;
}
```

I also tried rewriting it like this:

```
for (int iter = 0; iter < bisectionIterations; iter++) {
    bs_m = mix(bs_a, bs_b, 0.5);
    tmp = step(0.0, poly_calculatevalue(in_p, bs_m) * factor);
    bs_a = (1-tmp) * bs_m + tmp * bs_a;
    bs_b = tmp * bs_m + (1-tmp) * bs_b;
}
```

This code is executed in a computeshader in GLSL 430 on a Nvidia Gtx580. I only get a runtimme error (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) when calling glUseProgram and all following functions using this Program (SetUniform, DispatchCompute, etc.)

edit: The code actually works on my laptop with an AMD E-300 APU. What is the problem on the nvidia card?

Comment: Can you give the full error message? Does it have a line number with it? What's `poly_calculatevalue`? Is this GLES2.0/webgl?

Comment: `poly_calculatevalue` takes a polynomial struct (just an array of coefficients) and an x value and calculates the result.

Comment: `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is a GL error, not from GLSL. Have a look at [`glUseProgram`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUseProgram.xhtml) and see which of the cases that error occurs in. Do you check both compile and link status of your shaders?

Comment: I have already checked everything and it really only fails when I include that code, else everything works.

Comment: So you can simplify the shader and it works fine? Have you updated your drivers recently (could be a bug)? Have you checked that you can get errors printed by introducing a syntax error? Maybe starting from the simple shader, add small bits back in until it breaks to narrow down exactly what it is that causes the problem.

Comment: Are you checking shader compile status and link status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works actually just fine, the error propagated from somewhere else. There were some subtle array out-of-bounds errors in another loop, but the AMD driver just seems to ignore those edge cases.